# invoke a method from a new instance (reflect.New) with reflection

Tags: go, reflection, reflect

I want to instantiate an object in Go using reflection and call a method on it. However, I have no idea how to do this. I have tried something, but it does not work.

```golang
type foo struct {
    name string
}

func (f *foo) Bar() {
    f.name = "baz"
    fmt.Println("hi " + f.name)
}

func main() {
    t := reflect.TypeOf(&foo{})
    fooElement := reflect.New(t).Elem()
    fooElement.MethodByName("Bar").Call([]reflect.Value{})
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`reflect.New` works exactly like the `new` function, in that it returns an allocated pointer to the given type. This means you want pass the struct, not a pointer to the struct, to `reflect.TypeOf`.

```
t := reflect.TypeOf(foo{})
fooV := reflect.New(t)
```

Since you now have a pointer value of the correct type, you can call the method directly:

```
fooV.MethodByName("Bar").Call(nil)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/Aehrls4A8xB